# Can't Connect to Windows Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

When I try to connect to my Azure VM via RDP, I receive the error below

[image]

Is there a way to reset the password?

Comment: if anyone needs a solution for this one http://serverfault.com/questions/446699/how-to-reset-the-admin-password-on-vm-on-windows-azure/601027#601027

Answer (score 4):

Nasty error. The error message is very clear on what the error is!

Your password has expired. And this is absolutely bad thing in a cloud world. There are very few options you have, when you use Virtual Machines:

- Pay for a technical support and hope Microsoft can reset the password for you
- Probably you don't want to go this way but...

  - Shut down the VM
  - Download the VHD
  - Mount the VHD to a local Hyper-V
  - try some hacks to reset the password locally (I am out of ideas frankly)
  - Upload the VHD

Actually, let me put it that way: Imagine you installed windows on your Computer. A Windows Server version OS. You never created another user, other than local administrator. The server is running fine and you rarely log-in. Now you try to login but your password is expired! What do you do now?

**UPDATE**
Another thing you could try and hope it would work is following:

- Shutdown the VM
- Do backup of your VHD using [BLOB COPY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894037.aspx) to same or [different storage account](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/06/12/introducing-asynchronous-cross-account-copy-blob.aspx) (doesn't matter, just make sure you make a copy)
- go to your VM and navigate to Dashboard
- Click on Capture:
  [image]
- Agree and confirm all the questions
- Wait for the image to be created
- Now go to "Create new VM" -> From Gallery -> Find your own image
- Hope it will boot up and run

Note that I've never tried this exact procedure. The advise is to first generalize the OS before "capture-ing" it. So I don't know what the result will be. In best situation - you will have your OS back and running. In the worst situation you will have lost couple of hours.

Also note that with the copy of the original VHD you can always create another VM and will safely run, but you still will not be able to access it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably due to **Network Level Authentication** not providing the home screen **login interface** which typically allows the changing of passwords.

### Login screen interface

Check this [link](http://blog.mnewton.com/articles/Solution-RDP-The-Local-Security-Authority-cannot-be-contacted/) - If you could do the as the link instructs, you should be able to get in to change your password. Although before doing so, I would recommend you to restart your VM and re-download Azure's RDP connection file to see if you could enter.

### Enter via VNC (installing through Powershell)

By default, Azure's VM have PowerShell (port 5986) opened and enabled. Otherwise you could add the Endpoint from your Azure dashboard.

Once done, follow this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sriharsha/archive/2013/10/26/remote-powershell-in-azure-iaas-virtual-machines.aspx)

It uses a 3rd party tool, [uvnc](http://www.uvnc.com/downloads/ultravnc.html) to enter via VNC instead of RDP.

In any case, please do a capture of your attached hard disk before any of these so at least there's something you can fall back on. Hope this helps.

Comment: Just wondering, if the password is expired, how will we authenticate the Remote PowerShell session?

Comment: hmm. ur right. I was hoping a separate interface might provide a GUI for password changing. The reason why I listed VNC is that whenever I use teamviewer, I get to the home screen login page, as compared to entering via RDP into windows directly. In any case, here's an insightful page: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/0b1dd259-124c-4f48-b6a1-3df4aa3bbb53/vm-password-expiration

It mentions that using RDC on "Windows 8.1 Enterprise RTM" prompts the user to change his password with GUI as compared to your error when using "Windows 7 Pro". Worth a shot: |

Comment: Yep. I totally Understand the approach with VNC. But the RemotePowershell still requires user/password authentication, which if Expired will not work. Another shot worth trying is Terminals (terminals.codeplex.com) client. I think, if left with default it also shows the OS user prompt (but I am not sure)